# distance between ui components in swiftUi

Tags: swiftui

I want to have a constant distance between the image and the text , I also want to have a constant distance between the image and trailing anchor of the green box.using padding and increase the length of the text the problem appears as you seen win the picture. how can I solve this problem? how can use auto layout in swiftUi the same way as UIKit?

```
import SwiftUI

struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var orgName:String
    var imgName:String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame( height: 50)
                .padding([.trailing, .leading], 20)
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                .overlay(
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 10){
                        
                        Text("\(orgName)")
                            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50)
                        //Image( "\(imgName)")
                        Image( systemName: "phone.fill")}
                        
                    
                        //.padding(.trailing
                             // ,UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width-480)
                )

        }
    }
}

struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        SwiftUIView(orgName:"aaaaa", imgName:"aimg")
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: SwiftUI does not work like UIKit. The more hard coded values you put in the more you will have to “fix”  this screen will not look well on all devices. SwiftUI is more “one size fits all” vs “tailor made”

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI the order of modifiers matters! You need to set the `overlay` before the `padding`s.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below code for `Overlay HStackView` padding -

```
struct SwiftUIView: View {
    var orgName:String
    var imgName:String
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                .fill(Color.green)
                .frame( height: 50)
                .overlay(
                    HStack {
                        Text("\(orgName)")
                            .frame(width: .infinity, height: 50)
                        Image(systemName: "phone.fill")
                    }.padding(),
                    alignment: .trailing
                )
                .padding([.top, .bottom], 10)
                .padding([.trailing, .leading], 20)
        }
    }
}
```

Please check the result for your updated code here -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The important thing is ***swiftUI modifiers should use in correct order***

So You can simply use paddings instead of frames. Then this will responsive for all devices as well.

```
 import SwiftUI
            
            struct SwiftUIView: View {
                
                //MARK: - PRROPERTIES
                var orgName:String
                
                //MARK: - BODY
                var body: some View {
                    
                    HStack(spacing: 10){
                        
                        Spacer()
                        
                        Text("\(orgName)")
                        
                        Image( systemName: "phone.fill")
                        
                    }
                    .padding(.vertical , 15)
                    .padding(.horizontal, 10)
                    .background(
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 8)
                            .fill(Color.green)
                    )
                    .padding(.horizontal, 15)
                    
                }
            }
            
            
            //MARK: - PREVIEW
            struct SwiftUIView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
                static var previews: some View {
                    SwiftUIView(orgName:"aaaaaa")
                }
            }
```

[preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Npuxr.png)